# databricks on gcp cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cluster-computing, databricks

I'm trying to configure and run Databrics on GCP cluster after videos:
<youtube.com/watch?v=oHa4si8Risc>
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hquLYNN8nz8&t=267s
I performed permitions and increased CPUs etc.
While creating cluster in Databricks after running cluster is terminated with log "
Cluster terminated. Reason: Gcp Quota Exceeded". On GCP in Kubernetes Engine I can see my cluster with "Scale down blocked by pod". I read some comments about this error but in tutorials (attached and in GCP) there is nothing about setting pod, so I soppose the real error is somewhere else.

1. From Kubernete server- notification "blocked by pod"

[image]

2. Quotas:

[image]

3. From Databricks: server terminated:
   [image]

Edit:
I found gcp error message:
"reason": {
"code": "GCP_QUOTA_EXCEEDED",
"type": "CLIENT_ERROR",
"parameters": {
"gcp_error_message": "Compute Quota Exceeded for databricks-357705 in region us-central1: Quota: SSD_TOTAL_GB, used 0.0 and requested 1500.0 out of 500.0; Quota: N2_CPUS, used 0.0 and requested 12.0 out of 8.0"

Comment: Could you include the screenshot of the errors and your CPU and N2 CPU resource Quota and its regional Quota from IAM & Admin > Quotas page from your Project.

Answer (score 1):

Solved- the regions of quoted engines were not the same as project's region(project in us-central1, services in asia). Selecting each as us-central1 and performing additionas quotas worked. Thank you Siegfred V for slight suggestion.